# An undetermined measurable set and Borel Determinacy

Tags: logic, set-theory, descriptive-set-theory

The existence of a measurable set which is not determined can be proved using the Axiom of Choice (or even without it). Also, we know that $\{ \text{Borel sets} \} \subset \{ \text{measurable sets}  \}$. My questions are:

$\bullet$ Does this mean that we may find a Borel set which is not determined as a consequence of the existence of undetermined measurable sets?

$\bullet$ If so, does not this contradict the Borel Determinacy?

$\bullet$ If the answers of the above questions are no, do we only mean an undetermined measurable set $\in \{  \text{measurable sets} \} \setminus \{ \text{Borel sets} \}$?

$\bullet$ If there is a Borel set which is not determined for any other reason different from the one in the first question, can any one provide me with a reason, an example or  a reference?

PS: Any reference which discusses the above questions and includes an example would be appreciated.

Comment: Axiom of choice is necessary to prove there is a non-determined set...

Comment: https://mathoverow.net/questions/67366/non-measurable-sets-and-determinacy

Comment: Hamkins proved *if there is a non-determined set* then there is a non-determined measurable set, so your link does not refute my comment. In fact, it is consistent with ZF that every set of reals can be determined.

Comment: I see, so this does not include the existence of  non-determined Borel set in ZF? or in ZFC?

Comment: Let me stress again: You cannot have a non-determined Borel set in ZFC.

Comment: correction has been made!

Comment: @HanulJeon At the end of his proof, Hamkins writes "The conclusion, therefore, which does not use the axiom of choice, is that if there is a non-determined set,  then there is a non-determined set with measure 0 
. In particular, there is a non-determined set that is measurable" . So, we can construct an undetermined set of zero measure without the AC, and so we have a measurable set which is not determined without the AC.

Comment: @HanulJeon I'm not sure if this also means that the AC is not necessary for the non-determinacy itself (not the proof of the statement in the given link)

Comment: Choice is necessary to prove there is a non-Borel set to begin with.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks! I'm aware of that (a consequence of Vitali's result under the AC: Any measurable set with positive measure (in the real) contains a non measurable subset). My confusion lies in the fact that Hamkins mentions at the end of his proof.

Comment: There is an argument which does not use the axiom of choice: if $\Bbb R$ has a Hamel basis over $\Bbb Q$, then there exists a Vitali set. The fact the argument does not use choice does not mean that there are any Vitali sets or Hamel bases. Joel simply shows there that choice is not needed for the move from "undetermined" to "measurable and undetermined".

Comment: @True_False You are misreading Hamkins' comment; see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You've pretty much answered your own question, so let me confirm: All Borel sets are determined (the proof is due to Martin ~1975), a measurable, non-determined set hence is not Borel.

As far as references go, what precisely do you want a reference to? The proof that Borel sets are determined is covered in Kechris: Descriptive Set Theory. I don't know, off the top of my head, a reference for a non-determined, measurable set.

Comment: O.K. What about the fourth question? Is there any Borel set which is not determined in or out the ZFC for any reason at all? Does Martin's theorem mention any thing about this?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't decipher the meaning of that question. What do you have in mind? A weak sub theory of $\mathrm{ZFC}$ such that Borel sets/determinacy still makes sense but we don't have Borel determinacy?

Comment: What kind of a weak sub theory of ZF? Do you mean ZF+ a weak version of the AC (the axiom of countable choice for example)?

Comment: I am simply trying to understand what your question is, i.e. what "for any other reason" is supposed to mean in your original post.

Answer (score 3):

Stefan Mesken's answer addresses the bulk of your question; let me try to tie up the remaining loose end.

As noted in the comments, your parenthetical claim at the beginning of your question

> the existence of a measurable set which is not determined can be proved using the Axiom of Choice (or even without it)

is **false**: it is consistent with ZF (under mild consistency assumptions) that [every set is determined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_determinacy), measurable or non.

I think the issue here stems from a misreading of Hamkins' concluding comment. Hamkins states:

> "The conclusion, therefore, which does not use the axiom of choice, is that **if there is a non-determined set**, then there is a non-determined set with measure $0$. In particular, [**if there is a non-determined set**, then] there is a non-determined set that is measurable."

*(Emphasis/insertion mine.)* The crucial bit here is the hypothesis, "if there is a non-determined set:" Hamkins is *not* saying that ZF proves "there is a measurable non-determined set," he's only saying that ZF proves $$(*)\quad\mbox{"If there is a non-determined set, then there is a measurable non-determined set."}$$

Your final claim

> we can construct an undetermined set of zero measure without the AC, and so we have a measurable set which is not determined without the AC

is incorrect, since you're omitting the crucial hypothesis from $(*)$.

Comment: So, the antecedent in (*)  "If there is a non-determined set"  is impossible to hold in ZF only as every set is determined. Hence, no matter what comes after the implication will not affect the truth value of the whole statement.

Comment: @True_False "impossible to hold in ZF only as every set is determined" No, the point is that **it's consistent with ZF that** the antecedent of $(*)$ fails; in some models of ZF there are undetermined sets, in others there aren't. The point is that every model of ZF with *some* undetermined set has a *measurable* undetermined set.

Comment: As ZF is consistent with the failure of the antecedent of (*), does not the consistency provide a strong argument that opposes the existence of non determined sets? If so, why people bother to consider the possibility case of " a model of ZF with some undetermined sets", unless there are other reasons to construct them differ from the AC?

Comment: @True_False "As ZF is consistent with the failure of the antecedent of $(*)$, does not the consistency provide a strong argument that opposes the existence of non determined sets?" **Why would it?** ZF is also consistent with $\mathbb{R}$ being a countable union of countable sets, and lots of other nonsense. How does *consistency with ZF* suggest *plausibility*?

Comment: Maybe I expressed my questions badly. I will try again:

Under the assumption of ZF+“the failure of the antecedent of (*)”: Why we would think that there still might be some model of ZF +“the failure of the antecedent of (*)” that would have a non determined set; unless (still a question??), we reach a limit at which we cannot go further and claim that the antecedent of (*) is false by other reasons than the AC? (the axiom that is necessary to construct a non determined set, and we exclude it from the case we are discussing here)?

Comment: @True_False I can't really follow what you're asking, but here's a quick response. You write "Why we would think that there still might be some model of ZF +“the failure of the antecedent of $(*)$” that would have a non determined set." Note that "the failure of the antecedent of $(*)$" is just the statement "there is no nondetermined set." So, **there is no model** of ZF + "the failure of the antecedent of $(*)$" which has a non determined set. Maybe you meant: "Why would we think that there still might be some model of ZF + "There is an undetermined set?"

Comment: Well, ZF proves that if there is a model of ZF at all, then there is a model of ZF + "There is an undetermined set" (indeed, of full ZFC), so if you accept any model of ZF at all you have to also accept models of ZFC. Regardless, I still have no idea what you mean by "other reasons than the AC" - are you just asking "What axioms do we need to conclude the existence of a nondetermined set?"

Comment: Yes, the last line is part of my questions (of course other than the AC), and the other one: how do we know that we cannot go further to refute the consistency of ZF+ the failure of antecedent of (*) (maybe by finding  a model that would extend the system here without the AC)? Do we have a limit here? what is the guarantee?

Comment: @True_False "how do we know that we cannot go further to refute the consistency of ZF+ the failure of antecedent of $(*)$ (maybe by finding a model that would extend the system here without the AC)?" Now I'm totally confused. Before, you were trying to argue *against* determinacy ("As ZF is consistent with the failure of the antecedent of (*), does not the consistency provide a strong argument that opposes the existence of non determined sets?") but now you're looking for an inconsistency with it? I don't understand what it is you're trying to do - or what "limit" or "guarantee" refer to.

Comment: Maybe you're asking about their *consistency strengths*? ZF+AC (hence, ZF + "there is an undetermined game") is consistent if ZF is - and this is provable in an extremely weak theory (PA is already more than enough) - while ZF + "all sets are determined" (= ZF+AD) proves the consistency of ZFC, so has strictly higher consistency strength. As a consequence: we can easily prove that if ZF+AD is consistent then so is ZFC, but we don't know the converse.